# Adding to a list inside a class

Tags: c#, list, class

I have this class

```
public class User
{
   private string _name;
   public string UserName { get; set; }       
   public List<int> ControlNumber { get; set; }
   public User (string username)
   {
       _name = username;
   }
   public User()
   {
   }

}
```

And this function that fills the class.

```
User UserClass = new User(e.Key); //e.Key = user's name

public static void FillUserListClass(DataTable dt, ref UserClass)

{
    try
    {

        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
        {
            var row = dt.Rows[ctr];
            var userName = row["User"].ToString();

            if (UserList.ContainsKey(userName))
            {
                UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
            }
            else
            {
                _user.UserName = row["User"].ToString();
                _user.ControlNumber.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));

            }
              //print out
            Console.WriteLine("UserList Class: ");
            Console.WriteLine(_user.UserName);
            Console.WriteLine(_user.ControlNumber);


        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //conn.Close();
    }

}
```

However, at the `_user.ControlNumber.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));` line I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Any help?

What i'm trying to do is create a class for each user that contains the user's control numbers. I then want all of these classes to be placed into a dictionary for reference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to initialize your list in the constructor:

```
   public User (string username) : this()
   {
       _name = username;
   }
   public User()
   {
      this.ControlNumber = new List<int>();
   }
```

Otherwise, `ControlNumber` will have its default value of null.

Comment: What if I have a list inside another class, like this: https://pastebin.com/aWhfu8UM. I get a `Run-time exception (line 9): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error

Comment: @Si8 - Create a constructor for `DHold` and initialize `tlList ` to a new `List<ThisList>`

Comment: I +1 your answer because it led the way plus your comment. I was able to figure it out before, but thank you for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you initialize your lists before you use them!

**Corrected User-Class:**

```
public class User
{
   private string _name;
   public string UserName { get; set; }       
   public List<int> ControlNumber { get; set; }
   public User (string username) : this()
   {
       _name = username;
   }
   public User()
   {
       ControlNumber = new List<int>();
   }

}
```

And also, before converting `row["ControlNumber"]` to an integer, you should make sure it is not null.

```
if (row["ControlNumber"] != null)
{
user.ControlNumber.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialised the `ControlNumber`, you can do this in the constructor like

```
public User (string username)
{
    _name = username;
    ControlNumber = new List<int>();
}
```

or just before you attempt to `Add`

```
_user.ControlNumber = new List<int>();
_user.ControlNumber.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

By default, your `ControlNumber` property is set to `null`.

In your constructor, do the following to initialize it to an empty list:

```
this.ControlNumber = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate setting properties in constructor, so what I do is:

```
private List<int> _controlNumber;
public List<int> ControlNumber { 
    get { 
        if (_controlNumber == null)
            _controlNumber=new List<int>(); 

        return _controlNumber; 
    }

    set { _controlNumber = value } 
}
```

or simply

```
private List<int> _controlNumber = new List<int>();
public List<int> ControlNumber { 
    get { return _controlNumber; } 
    set { _controlNumber = value } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `_user`?
I dont see it in your example.