# Adding data to a list inside a class

Tags: c#, list, class

I want to fill a `list<int>` inside a `class` I can't get it to work.
(Some / Most of the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966712/adding-to-a-list-inside-a-class)

The class:

```
    class Fiu
    {
        public int feleseg { get; set; }
        public List<int> preferencia { get; set; }
        public Fiu (int _feleseg) : this()
            {
                feleseg = _feleseg;
            }
        public Fiu()
        {
            this.preferencia = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

The code:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Fiu ujfiu = new Fiu(0);
            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            {
                ujfiu.preferencia[j-1] = 1;                      
            }
        }
```

The main goal would be filling it from excel, but right now it doesn't even put 1-s in. I don't know what's wrong.
I get a "Argument out of range exception unhandled" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace This:

```
ujfiu.preferencia[j-1] = 1;
```

With This:

```
ujfiu.preferencia.Add(1);
```